# Sharepoint online - large list

Tags: list-view

I may have asked this qu before - but I am still stuck.
I have an online sharepoint site (2013) subscription and am developing a team site for my co workers.
As part of this development I uploaded some tables from access 2010 and this resulted in the creation of a sharepoint list of 7517 items which in excess of the 5000 item limit.
I want to delete this table and start again. No matter which route I use the site will not let me delete the list. I have even tried loading sharepoint designer 2013 on my local PC but even when edited from there the site will not accept the deletion.
I have looked at the source code below but cannot edit it to remove the list or any throttling restriction.

Here is the error I get when tried to delete:

The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

Technical Details

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 7d28289c-02a4-8070-e6be-2a59f49935d5

Date and Time: 6/23/2013 2:26:20 AM

and here is the source code for the list:

<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="ApplicationPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

     - 
    

    


    





    


        
        
  
            
            
            
            
            
            
             
           
           
           



30clienttemplates.jsmain.xsl

Is there some kind soul who can help me before I completely loose the plot????
Graham

Answer (score 1):

You have SharePoint online subscription and you should open a ticket and the support will do this for you. I have faced some unexpected issues like yours,  but support guys helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try deleting the items in the list first. Bring it down to below 5000 and then try deleting the list.